# Randomly losing wi-fi connection 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I have fresh install Ubuntu 15.10 wily Gnome Shell.

Sometimes, randomly it lose wi-fi connection.

During this time, my laptop is able to use wi-fi without any issue. 
I do nothing and after 1-5 minutes wi-fi connection get back.

How i can diagnose with? I have installed this [drivers rtl8192cu-fixes](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes).

Here is [`wireless-info`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13238291/).

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i should be more clear, i tested and for now it lost a wifi connection, not internet(tried to `ping 192.168.1.1` router.). Also i have already WPA2-AES settings and 11bgn mixed in the router, disable IPv6.  I set other your recommendations. I Wait for any improvements.